# Как сайт может понимать, что я захожу на него из двух вкладок

Tags: веб-программирование, http

Откуда у сайта информация, что я на него захожу с одной машины одновременно 2 раза? Пробовал использовать разные сокс прокси, разные браузеры. К тому же, общий вайфай (1 айпи) на 2 компьютера. С обоих компов можно зайти на сайт одновременно. А с одного компа 2 раза - никак.

Разве браузер может отсылать информацию о моем оборудовании без моего ведома?

Comment: С одного компа и разных браузеров никак?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: `localStorage`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4079280/276994

Comment: почитай,  у меня в вопросе по ссылке дубликате, есть подробный ответ... который принятый